# Setting up square image as background

Tags: android, android-image, android-background, androidsvg

I have square image and I need to set that image as background. But I need that image to render differently in portrait and landscape mode.

As shown in the picture, the same image should be applied for both landscape and portrait but each should show different part of the image maintaining the same pivot point. The black dot in the image represents the pivot point.

Is it achievable with the same image? I can do with two different images.

Is it achievable with svg image?

[image]

Comment: Are you using the AndroidSVG library to render actual SVGs? Or are you using VectorDrawables?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are actually using an SVG image for your image...

All you should have to do is:

1. provide an appropriate `viewBox`
2. set the SVG to `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`. This setting is equivalent to CSS `background-zise: cover`.

**Demo**

```css
svg:nth-child(1) {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

svg:nth-child(2) {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF2FB.png" width="300" height="300"/>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF2FB.png" width="300" height="300"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul LeBeau for the answer. But, I think your answer is for the web.
I actually asked question for Android.

Comment: I asked above whether you were using actual SVGs or not. But you did not answer. 
 My solution (using `preserveAspectRation`) should work as long as you are using an SVG rendering library for Android that supports it.  My one, AndroidSVG, does.

Comment: Designer provided svg file. I need to import it inside Android Studio as vector drawable. Do you believe, I still have luck?

Comment: Ok. Then in that case, no. Just convert the SVG and use `scaleType="centerCrop"` on your ImageView.